# How to remove old phones from google maps?

Tags: macos, ios

I just notices there are several old phones listed when I choose “send to phone” in google maps.  I searched and followed several sets of directions but could not remove them.

They are not listed in my devices in google security and only show up in that section of maps.  Some of them haven’t been used in 3-4 years

Can anyone tell me how to get all those old devices removed?

I guess I am just stuck with all my old phones in the "send to my phone" list?  https://support.google.com/maps/thread/5020901?hl=en

Comment: which "several sets of directions"? We cannot see over your shoulder, you have to tell us what you already did.

Comment: @Tetsujin probably the first several from this search https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=google+remove+old+phones  when i go into "my devices" I dont see the old phones, but they do appear in Google maps